# Apache Beam Python split sentence into key, value pair for every word

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have data that contains a sentence and a group(label) --> key, value pair is (group, sentence) to start and I want to split the sentence into words such that I end up with (group, word) pairs for all words in all sentences. How can I do this within a pipeline? Consider this test example

```
test_input = [{'group': '1', 'sentence': 'This is a sentence'},
              {'group': '1', 'sentence': 'This is another sentence'},
              {'group': '2', 'sentence': 'Here is a third sentence'},
              {'group': '3', 'sentence': 'The last example'}]

test_transformation = (test_input
                       | 'split' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: (x["group"], x["sentence"].split()))
                      )

test_transformation
```

The example above does split the sentence into a list of words, but the entire list is paired with the word. How can I further break down this list?  The output for the first row is below:

```
['1',['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']]
```

Whereas what I would want is something more like

```
[('1', 'This'), ('1', 'is'), ('1', 'a'), ('1', 'sentence')]
```

This feels as if it should be do-able but I cannot figure out how to to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be more of a Python question than a Beam question, because neither the issue itself nor the solution involve Beam APIs. You can use a Python [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> x = {'group': '1', 'sentence': 'This is a sentence'}

>>> (x['group'], x['sentence'].split())
('1', ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence'])

>>> [(x['group'], word) for word in x['sentence'].split()]
[('1', 'This'), ('1', 'is'), ('1', 'a'), ('1', 'sentence')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your lambda to produce a list containing one output tuple for each word in the sentence. Something like:

```
test_transformation = (test_input
                    | 'split' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: [(x["group"], word) for word in x["sentence"].split()))
                    )
```